# findbysql searching 2 tables

Tags: yii

i am using this code to search 2 tables where $id is a variable

$id=$_REQUEST['company_id'];

$result=User::model()->findBysql('select a.email from user a , recruiter b where a.id=b.user_id and b.company_id=$id');

i am getting error this code is not working any ideas please

Comment: Are you having a problem with it?  What's your question?

Comment: please use paramaters, not sql injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got help from yii live chat they told me because id is variable the sql query  should be in double quotes and id in {}

$result = User::model()->findBysql("select a.email from user a , recruiter b where a.id=b.user_id and b.company_id={$id}");

Thanks for the answers

Answer (score 1):

1) Never user $_REQUEST. You could either user Yii::app()->request->getParam('company_id') or search in respectively $_GET/$_POST

2)

```
$result = User::model()->find(array(
    'condition' => 'r.company_id=:company_id',
    'join' => 'INNER JOIN recruiter r ON t.id = r.user_id',
    'params' => array(
        ':company_id' => $id
    )
));
```

3) You probably want to define the recruiter as User's model relation

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with the code you've written here is that your sql string in enclosed with single quotes. But I don't know if it's a typo here or it's the actual problem. Could you please give us the error message?